# Set Timeout in JTA configuration

Tags: java, tomcat7, jta

JTA transaction unexpectedly rolled back (maybe due to a timeout); the nested exception is

```
javax.transaction.RollbackException: The transaction was set to rollback only
```

I get an timeout exception due to JPA: how can I increase the time needed for the transaction?

Where should I include the parameter to resolve this?

I am using tomcat 7.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think JTA is a feature of Tomcat 7, it has been added to your Tomcat 7 environment. You'll have to figure out what your JTA implementation is and either read the docs or update your question here with more relevant information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parameter that you want to change is the maximum timeout for your JTA transaction.

If you're using Atomikos (which I believe is what most people use with Tomcat), you can set that via the `com.atomikos.icatch.max_timeout` property or via the `com.atomikos.icatch.default_jta_timeout` property. This property can be set either via a JVM command line parameter, or via Spring Integration (described [here](http://www.atomikos.com/Documentation/SpringIntegration#Setting_Atomikos_System_Properti)).

More information about the configuration (JTA) properties for Atomikos can be found [here](http://www.atomikos.com/Documentation/JtaProperties).

If you're using Bitronix, you can add a `bitronix-default-config.properties` file to your classpath, and then add a `bitronix.tm.timer.defaultTransactionTimeout=<value>` line to that file. See [here](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/BTM/Configuration#Configuration-Timerssettings) for more info.